# Colors in Node-Red Diagram

Tags: node-red

I send 4 different topics to one diagram. All is well and I'm seeing 4 lines in the diagram.
But after I restart node-red the order of the 4 topics may have changed and so the colors are changing too.

Is there a way to define which msg/topic results in which color?

Comment: I have the same question and found no answer so far :-(

Comment: @Lori - I never found an answer to this. It's always some kind of random how the color map to the topics.